# Testing 16K SRAM in TL866 II Plus?

Tags: sram, test-equipment, tl866, diagnostics

I have a GoldStar GM76C28A-10 16K (2048 x 8) SRAM DIP chip that I want to test in my TL866 II Plus. I don't see this chip in the list of known chips in the Xgpro v11.60 software and none of the "Standard SRAM" options are for 16K.

Is it possible to test this chip in this device?

Comment: The standard 6116 SRAM (2Kx8 bit) pinout is identical to that of the GM76C28A.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the details provided by the interface. When I choose 6116 it says "Flash Size: 2048 bytes" in the Device.Info tab pane and I thought this was describing the capacity of the entire chip. Is this instead describing the bank size where the multiple is arbitrary?